# jQuery mousedown() only runs once

Tags: jquery, mousedown

I'm trying to create a script to implement a tab functionality because .tabs() wasn't an option; it required them to be a list.
It seems to work once, but clicking either div / tab again doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var mt = $("#maintab");
  var at = $("#admintab");

  $("#tab-2").hide();  
  mt.css('background-color','#00FF00');
  mt.css('color','black');

  mt.mousedown(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color','#00FF00');
    $(this).css('color','black');
      at.css('background-color','black');
      at.css('color','#00FF00');
        $("#tab-2").hide();
        $("#tab-1").show();
  });

  at.mousedown(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color','#00FF00');
    $(this).css('color','black');
      mt.css('background-color','black');
      mt.css('color','#00FF00');
        $("#tab-1").hide();
        $("#tab-2").show();
  });

});
```

What could be the issue? I've linked to the latest jQuery and UI in the Markup as well as gone through to check the id's and classes. Everything checks out.
here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S7FLg/

Comment: A [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to see the problem.

Comment: Your fiddle is a little...verbose. See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) guidelines on examples. Honestly, that helps when debugging anyway--find the smallest amount of code that you can reproduce the problem with, and the error tends to stick out more readily.

Comment: I'm sure there are many people who would like to help, but given the complexity of the question it will be difficult. Is your question just regarding setting up vertical tabs on a webpage?

Comment: @TimSPQR Vertical tabs is the implementation I am looking for, it is also to have them at a right angle, rather than horizontal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your are using duplicate `id`, which is one of the **MUST NOT DO THING** in HTML. In Short ,`id` attributes must be unique within the whole document.

So to counter that you should use `class` instead ...

```
<p  class="taba maintab">Main</p>
<p  class="taba admintab">Admin</p>
```

### And you can see the Updated [Working Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/S7FLg/2/)

P.S

I have used the existing code in fiddle and haven't change the `id` of the the `<p>`as it distort the design. And , Why use two different block of tabs ? The Admin and Main tab are common for both div.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I had looked up using class for this, but I made the mistake of thinking an id simply functioned like a second class. I'm glad you went through the time to look through my "verbose" markup. I'll be sure to remember this from now on. However, in your fiddle the tabs don't apply the CSS to appear highlighted unless clicked twice.

Answer (score 0):

if you use event delegation, the problem doesn't seem to appear: http://jsfiddle.net/S7FLg/3/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var mt = $("#maintab");
  var att = $("#admintab");

  $("#tab-2").hide();  
  mt.css('background-color','#00FF00');
  mt.css('color','black');

  $(document).on('mousedown','#maintab',function() {
    $(this).css('background-color','#00FF00');
    $(this).css('color','black');
      att.css('background-color','black');
      att.css('color','#00FF00');
        $("#tab-2").hide();
        $("#tab-1").show();
  });

  $(document).on('mousedown','#admintab',function() {
    $(this).css('background-color','#00FF00');
    $(this).css('color','black');
      mt.css('background-color','black');
      mt.css('color','#00FF00');
        $("#tab-1").hide();
        $("#tab-2").show();
  });

});
```